# Typescript prop discrimination in react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typeerror

I'm creating a dynamic Widget, which can be either empty or populated. It should be by default empty. When `populated={true}`, I'd like the `totalGross` and `totalNet` values to be required. Otherwise, those 2 props shouldn't be allowed.

For that, I'm trying to use a discriminating type (`WidgetBodyProps`). However, TypeScript complains because `totalNet` & `totalGross` are required props in `<WidgetBodyPopulated />`

```js
type WidgetBodyProps =
    | { isEmpty?: false; totalNet: string; totalGross: string }
    | { isEmpty: true; totalNet?: never; totalGross?: never };

type WidgetProps = WidgetHeaderProps & WidgetBodyProps;

const Widget = (props: WidgetProps) => {
    const { title = "", isEmpty = true, totalNet, totalGross } = props;

    return (
        <Card>
            <Box>
                <WidgetHeader title={title} />
                <Divider my="4" />
                {isEmpty ? (
                    <WidgetBodyEmpty flex="1" />
                ) : (
                    <WidgetBodyPopulated totalNet={totalNet} totalGross={totalGross} />
                )}
            </Box>
        </Card>
    );
};
```

How can I fix this Typescript Error?
[image: TS Error]

Comment: Assigning defaults for `totalNet` and `totalGross` should fix up the immediate error (i.e. `totalNet = '', totalGross = ''`). However, I think the way `WidgetBodyProps` seems a bit kludgy, especially the `never` usages. I guess the latter is because you want to dodge using type guards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you destructure the props, Typescript forgets they were ever related. So a test on one variable, will not discriminate the type of another. But at the time that you destructure `props` you haven't tested it's type, so all variables are typed with all possibilities.

However, if you avoid destructuring, then Typescript can keep tabs on the type of `props`. This way testing a preperty of props narrows the type of props are you are expecting.

```
{props.isEmpty ? (
    <WidgetBodyEmpty flex="1" />
) : (
    <WidgetBodyPopulated
      totalNet={props.totalNet}
      totalGross={props.totalGross}
    />
)}
```

Then you can even simplify those props to:

```
type WidgetBodyProps =
    | { isEmpty?: false; totalNet: string; totalGross: string }
    | { isEmpty: true };
```

Because you never access `.totalNet` without checking `.isEmpty` first.

[Working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=25&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAdWABMBzJGAIQkcoAUcwAznAC8pOOLgAfOAG84wAQFFwVAPwAuOJhQAbAUgDccGBBi6Acm00CYUYADtmRk2Z0BxHAIHXbD5nABfMQlpOQVlMCpNWwBXWgCDckwY+wxgCHt6JlYYAAowfm8sljZObj4IQQBKWWDxIhgYqEyAHkZgADcAPjqJcRkCyoEAOnCVSjhVOFzevr6WhhKOLkoIqjgAeh65iRrNGZ2dhezSlZ5KmJ0UGCRGY1MLNmEBwuGXR5gA+9cPCC9nwaCN4PdyeARfLazXZBeYbdrdUhBJIpNIZYo5Mqrca5GoyXoNJqteGbHpBZKpGDpTKLDFnC5XG6MXIyd46SwwAA0310vy8AU0LJB7J8dkcXNZvKKNlFzACuPxbEJcDanRJiNIQA)

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error occurs because Typescript doesn't trust you that something isn't null. Use a [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) to tell Typescript that it can trust that you know what you're doing and you won't feed it a null. The other option would be to ensure the variables in question are properly set to be empty strings.